# Why does the Stack Overflow login form tell you whether a specific login exists or not?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, login, security, error-message

I've noticed something on the [Stack Overflow login page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/login): detecting if an email address has been used by a user for registration is actually possible.

In short, when you want to log in with an email that **is not registered**, you are provided with an error message that states that there is no account with the email you provided.

[image: Screen shot of the "We could not find an account for that email address" message]

If you provide an email that a user **used to register on Stack Overflow** but **provide a wrong password**, the error message states that the password you used doesn't match the one used for registration.

[image: Screen shot of the "The password is incorrect" message]

<sup>(I have intentionally hidden my personal email address from the screenshot)</sup>

I have been told on many occasions (in both job contracts and school lessons) that when a combination of login/password is wrong, the error message should not specify whether it's the email or the password that is wrong. It should rather tell the user that either one of them is incorrect without specifying which one exactly, so as not to indicate if a specific login exists or not.

So why doesn't the Stack Overflow login form follow this (what I consider a) basic security rule?

Comment: I take your point but this is not a banking site...I would presume that SE want to make it easy for us to get back into our accounts.

Comment: @Paulie_D: I'm sure that SE intended this behavior in order to make our life easier on this level but I wouldn't like for someone to log into my account and post dummy questions / answers (that are most likely to be downvoted) or worse, spamming the site (and makes me eligible for the -100 rep points penalty). My SO account is linked to my LinkedIn profile and is shown on my professional website and CV.

Comment: @D4V1D try changing your password into something other than '123456' :-)

Comment: @Glorfindel: For sure, my password is a bit more complex than `123456` but I'm still concerned by this security matter and think that's worth asking about it on meta :)

Comment: additional info: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/62667/29644

Comment: @rene: Thanks for this interesting thread (especially the last paragraph of the linked answer which states that giving generic error message is at cost of user experience).

Comment: *So recruiters could easily collect programming expert emails to spam to!*

Comment: ^^ lol, you are even more cynical than I am:(

Comment: I actually agreed with the OP when I started reading this post. But I'm old so I tend toward paranoia rather than thinking about a user's feelings or whether remembering their email address is hard. That being said, I think this post actually did change my mind on the topic and I plan to give more meaningful login error messages going forward.
Thanks again SO!

Comment: You might have been told that its always the best thing to do but its not universally agreed by everybody. You can find more discussions and opinions about it on security stack exchange and UX stack exchange.

Comment: Tbh this thought is somewhat outdated and never even meant much in the first place. It is security through obscurity but it doesn't really work. Security should be more orientated around validating the source of the input and the potential for an ongoing attack on that user's details.

Comment: A recent [question on \[security.se\]](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/88815) asks the same question in context of gmail.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Many people are very quick to point out that hinting that an email exists in the system as part of a login error is a bad idea. What most people don't talk about is that **nearly all of those systems that give vague error messages like "Either your email or password is wrong", will flat out tell you "That email already exists" on a sign up page, rendering that "security enhancement" on the log in page useless.**

StackExchange is doing the correct thing for their use case. The usability gain is worth it, because if someone really wanted to figure out what emails are valid and being used, they'll just check the signup forms.

Comment: +1. On a site where registration is open and free, having an unclear error message worsens UX and provides no security benefit unless you *also* change registration to say something like "if that email is not already registered, we have sent a link with further instructions"... I haven't seen anyone do that yet.

Comment: @JacobRaihle: Just change the model: In principle, an account exists for *every* email-address. Most just aren't fully established yet. Thus, account-creation is just a special-case of account-recovery.

Comment: @JacobRaihle I think you've made the most important point here - *when the registration is open and free*, there is no way to make account creation+login actions completely opaque to attackers but usable for users. A bank would still have this problem if they are an internet bank and you create your login credentials *before* they need any more financially oriented information that would slow the discovery process down. Which, itself hints at the proper solution for a site like this one: rate limit any action that could lead to information discovery, making it impractical for attackers.

Comment: I don't think giving a general message is for "security enhancement", it's because even though the provided email is existing, the system cannot tell for sure if the email or password is incorrect... SO just assumes that the email is correctly entered if it can find one in it's database (which may confuse some users very rarely, but I wouldn't mind that)...

Comment: @nategood You could also gauge whether an email address is on their system by following the procedure for forgotten passwords, this is how I usually check to see if I actually have an account before trying to remember/guess my password!

Comment: @Troyseph: Some systems let you know that "*an email has been sent to the email provided*" even though the email has not been used to register on the site.

Comment: @D4V1D precisely **some**... I'd say it was yet another security risk overlooked by many!

Answer (score 34):

Jeff Atwood addressed this point in a relatively recent blog post relating to his experience making a login for Discourse. I assume the same mentality is held at Stack Overflow:

> OK, so we know that email is de-facto identity for most people, and this is a logical and necessary state of affairs. But which of my 10 email addresses did I use to log into your site?
>
> This was the source of a long discussion at Discourse about whether it made sense to reveal to the user, when they enter an email address in the "forgot password" form, whether we have that email address on file. On many websites, here's the sort of message you'll see after entering an email address in the forgot password form:
>
> > If an account matches name@example.com, you should receive an email
> >      with instructions on how to reset your password shortly.
>
> Note the coy "if" there, which is a hedge against all the security implications of revealing whether a given email address exists on the site just by typing it into the forgot password form.
>
> We're deadly serious about picking safe defaults for Discourse, so out of the box you won't get exploited or abused or overrun with spammers. But after experiencing the real world "which email did we use here again?" login state on dozens of Discourse instances ourselves, **we realized that, in this specific case, being user friendly is way more important than being secure.**

[The God Login, Jeff Atwood, Jan 2015](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-god-login/)

Answer (score 16):

As others in the comments said - Stack Overflow isn't a bank. We don't need to have the kind of security that a bank does.

Additionally (also mentioned in comments), there is a trade off between making something secure and making it easy to use.

In this case, we have chosen on the side of usability. In the worst case, we are leaking that someone is using the Stack Exchange network with that email address.

Comment: Anyway, there's another way to find that out: Try to open a new account with the email-address...

Comment: Given that many people reuse their passwords, there's a good chance some users have the same or similar password for banking

Comment: @Deduplicator There are ways around that too - "a confirmation email has been sent to xyz@example.com", even if the account already exists etc.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Not if that confirmation message for the password reset functionality is always shown (even if the e-mail doesn't exist). Anyway, there is another way to determine whether an e-mail is available and that is trying to see if there is a correlation between request time and e-mail existence. If the e-mail exists, then there will likely be a hash check which takes some time.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I'm not sure random delays would [help](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/can-i-prevent-timing-attacks-with-random-delays). They would probably just slow down the attacker a bit.